# Multiple "panes" view in single document Windows application

Tags: windows, winapi, mfc

I'm trying to write an editor for game scenes. So far, I'm able to present results in a single window. However, I would like to have several "panes", for example for material properties or resources preview.

The good example would be Blender layout:
[image]

I know MFC and WinAPI, I wouldn't rather use Qt, since it's not free.

Comment: Those sidebar windows could be CControlbar windows, CPane windows ... and MFC could do that. What is the problem ?

Comment: I think that the problem is, I don't want to use Dialog window. I'm using Document-View single document approach. So what you're saying, those things are controls? Like buttons? And you add them to my main View? I was rather thinking that I need separate Window (derived from CWnd) and somehow split the view....

Comment: Do ahead and create multiple windows.

Comment: No, once you create a SDI app, those sidebar windows could be CPaneWnd that could have behavior that you want (dock them, drag&drop, hide, autohide, etc.) and where you can put any control on them. Just check "Advanced frame panes" on step 6 when you create SDI app.

Comment: Ok, but in my main app, I have this call: AddDocTemplate(...), which consist of my View, Frame and Document. So where should I "add" this CPaneWnd?

Comment: Nota bene, you can add any number of CPaneWnd's, though wizard allow you to add a one of any kind of pane window. How ? After you create desired pane, then add manually (writing code) after project creation.

Comment: "I know MFC and WinAPI, I wouldn't rather use Qt, since it's not free." — The statement does not make any sense as MFC is not free.

Comment: What do you mean "MFC is not free"? AFAIK, you don't need any license for shipping MFC applications, and if you want to ship Qt application, you need a commercial license.

Answer (score 0):

I did it on a commercial application and it works fine:

1. Create a Single Document application
2. Read about `CDockablePane`, then look into the MFC Feature Pack exanples.
3. Finally implement the CDockablePanes and their contents
4. Arrange them the way you want by docking them to your own `CFrameWndEx`-derived class.